# How to move the root folder in intellij 2016?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

For backup purpose, I would like to move the root folder

```
C:\Users\userName\.IdeaIC2016
```

to another place like in `d:\`

How to do it smoothly?

Comment: maybe https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207240985-Changing-IDE-default-directories-used-for-config-plugins-and-caches-storage

Answer (score 1):

Here, below, put in clear for next users/people:

Locations can be changed by editing the following file:
IDE_HOME\bin\idea.properties

Follow the comments in idea.properties file to change the defaults, make sure to un-comment the lines defining these properties:

```
idea.config.path
idea.system.path
idea.plugins.path
idea.log.path
```